# Non-native English speakers and asking a bilingual question

Tags: discussion, english

I recently came across a question by a user whose mother tongue is French. I am bilingual, and his question wasn't asked clearly in English. After asking the OP to post the question in both English and French, I was accosted saying "This is an English-only site! Don't suggest such a thing!"

Personally, if I came across a question that was asked in two languages, as long as English is there - I wouldn't give a hoot.

Why is Stack Overflow so exclusively English and does not accept an OP's question if they put in the time and effort to be well understood?

Comment: As a non-native English speaking guy from Europe, I want my whole web in English only, maybe except local news from my home country. This multilingual thing we humans are doing is such a perf downer.

Comment: although I appreciate the fact that a global language would be/ is effective in certain fields, I can't say I would go as far as abolishing all languages on the web but for English. I can see the proof that within language lies a lot of our methods of reasoning. And I love how we all reason differently... personally.

Comment: @Alex I disagree wholeheartedly. Language is intrinsically deeply rooted in and linked with culture. So much culture would be lost if we all standardised on one language. Within Europe I can kind of understand that, since we're all sharing an very similar culture anyway. But if you look at extremely different cultures and languages, you'd be throwing away a lot by abolishing them. Live with the diversity, even if it sometimes makes you slightly less efficient... :)

Comment: @deceze I don't see how most languages have more than associative connections with the culture in question. Or do you suggest that our social norms and traditions in any way is causally connected with e.g. the grammar and the set of words we use?

Comment: @Alex Certain types of living have produced the need to express certain types of thoughts, which has produced the words we use today in our language. There are many words in different languages which are virtually impossible to translate into other languages exactly; the word, the idea, the thought, the concept simply does not exist outside that language, at least not in such a compact and commonly used form that a word has been created for it. The presence of such words enables the (more efficient) exchange of ideas about that topic in that language. I wouldn't want to miss that.

Comment: Well, we might have different opinions on the value of many spoken languages in the world. But any way, to agree on one main common language for one domain, like for example science or the general web, does not have to mean that the other languages does not have a right to thrive outside of those domains. As long as everyone at least knows one common language I'm pleased, then they can use whatever languages they want on the side.

Comment: @Alex: Off topic; Regarding the culture influencing the words we use, there is suspicion that this is the case. I remember a documentary where it was explained that Russian tends to use more group-based sentences (preferring to use 'us' over singular forms when speaking of generally applicable statements). This might explain why communism was prevalent there. There also seems to be a correlation between acceptance of non-heterosexuals, and languages that do not use a gender in possessive nouns (e.g. French. They use gender, but not to signify the owner's gender; but the object's gender)

Comment: @Flater FWIW: As someone who speaks Japanese, I can attest that it contains a ton of expressions, words and grammatical structures to express feelings and interpersonal relationships. It is fantastic for expressing subtle nuances in that field which would just seem extremely stilted or awkward in most western languages. It gives me a whole new outlook on this topic I never had before and has to some extend made me a more well rounded individual, I think. #offtopic #stopthatnow ;)

Comment: @deceze "Certain types of living [...] produced the words we use today [...]" Sure, that's true, but (and I'm not advocating we should do this) if we all switched to one language, then those types of living would just mean that we make new words in that language? Or, just do what English already does, and steal the word wholesale from the other language... spell it out phonetically and be done with it. Again, not advocating that we should do this, only saying you can't argue that English can't compensate for languages that have exclusive words.

Comment: @deceze Cont'd: E.g. the Portuguese 'saudade' which "doesn't have a direct translation in English" but can be defined in English quite easily. Why can't we just say "saudade" in the middle of our English sentence and keep talking? If someone asks what it means, we tell them "immense, nostalgic longing" and that's that. Isn't that enough to make it a word in English? I suppose I'm getting into Linguistics here.

Comment: #offtopic No language is perfect so I think having a universal language is not a good idea. A language is not just words so you can't just add words to fix it. Anyone who believes in linguistic relativity will appreciate using many languages.

Comment: @TylerH #offtopic Expressions and words often make sense in their original language, because they're based off of similar words/concepts. In many languages nouns are glued together to form a new compound word with a new meaning (English does very little of that, often preferring to add new words instead). A native speaker can intuitively understand those new words and meanings, at least partially. If you kept adding foreign words to English, it'd be very hard to learn all those words out of context easily. Language builds upon existing language.

Comment: @TylerH #offtopic #contd Not to mention that different grammars are suited for different conversations. I can be extremely precise in German, because it requires a lot of precise information embedded in its grammatical constructs. I can more easily talk about technical stuff in English, because it's so easy to make up new words and meanings in it which are nevertheless understood. I can have a very quick back and forth discussion in Japanese, because it requires extremely little sentence structure and a single word contains a lot of grammatical information and nuance.

Comment: How can one be a software developer without at least English reading and writing skills? What about the documentation? Tutorials? These are mainly in English. It's far easier to learn a natural language like English than to learn programming. If someone finds it hard to do the former then the latter seems to be almost impossible. I'm sorry but that's my opinion. I'm not a native speaker as well but even when I make mistakes it's easy to understand me.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo I've raised the very same argument before when these debates pop up. If one does not understand English well enough to scrape together a basic, somewhat grammatically coherent question, one cannot possibly do any programming work. There are many professions in the world that don't require basic English skills. Tough luck: computer programmer is not one of them.

Comment: @Elmo Agreed, English is the lingua franca of programming, and not being able to at least comprehend English cuts you out of a lot of the latest developments and resources. However, there are a ton of programmers writing for, say, embedded systems in the same language that has always existed forever and which hasn't changed a bit in the last decade or two and for which enough books have been published in their native tongue...

Comment: @deceze still there is a huge difference in difficulty level between programming and learning a natural language. I just can't imagine a software developer who is unable to learn basic English. I agree with all arguments about culture being related to language. But isn't the programmers world somehow tied with English? Besides Brainfuck and other academic programming languages, please enlist at least one which doesn't involve an English based keyword.

Comment: @Elmo I think you overestimate people's ability to learn other languages. I know plenty of people who struggle even with basic English, or with expressing themselves in their own language. Some people simply do not have a brain for languages, it seems. This may have no impact on their ability to write code though. At some point, keywords just become yet another foreign word you know how to use, but don't really understand. As mentioned above, we may know now how to use "saudade", but we may not actually understand it at a fundamental level or even know how to pronounce it correctly.

Comment: @Elmo contd... Having said that, I believe the best programmers all have an innate ability to learn languages, including English, and most programmers who have shown to be more or less incapable of learning English also regularly tend to be not great at programming. One can argue about why that is, maybe both inabilities stem from the same lack of some basic understanding of something, or both things use the same areas of the brain. That still means that there are many programmers out there who do not speak English [very well] (...yeah, you may fill in the blanks here...).

Comment: It just seems to me that even learning a new language, one must have at least another to compare with in order to develop an understanding of the new language. I find similarities between certain programming languages just as I do between English and French - it's in those personal connections that understanding flourishes... not in stifling them. What I'm saying is, we're all at a different level of English, so why not lend a hand up the ladder? Just as we do up the ladder of programming...

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo: Learning English can be quite hard for people whose native tongue is not from the IndoEuropean family (case in point: _all your base are belong to us_). Also, how can you even compare learning a couple ten keywords (when you wrote: _please enlist at least one which doesn't involve an English based keyword_) with learning a whole language?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Anecdotal evidence: once an obviously German speaker put up a question which I stumbled across, and he clearly had an issue with expressing a crucial detail in English, which came out somewhat confusing due to an awkward and incorrect choice of words. I asked him in the comments to clarify that particular part in German. That cleared up the whole question, I corrected it and provided an answer in English. All were happy. There is only one comment in German buried somewhere on SO now.

As long as the OP's English is good enough and he merely has trouble with a few specific expressions that would be easier to convey in his native language, I don't see a problem with clarifying that in the *comments*. The body of the question itself should be kept in English only (to the extend that it doesn't happen to touch on languages by its topic, of course). If the OP's English is obviously so bad that the whole conversation, including the answer, would need to be held in another language, then SO is probably not the right site for him.

The only thing we do not want is to create "ghettos" of foreign language speakers. The SO system is based on continuous free-for-all community peer review of everything. Language barriers break that aspect, it would keep people from reviewing each other. As long as that isn't an issue, a tiny splash of language doesn't hurt, IMO. I'll admit that this is a very, very slippery slope though.

Comment: I like this answer, especially because we specify at the Non-English Question Policy about questions, but it does not directs that comments can't be made in another language.

Comment: I have in the past left comments in Dutch @HugoRocha to clarify an issue, though I did provide a translation in English as well, if only to keep others in the loop. And of course those were cleaned up once the issue was settled.

Comment: Yes, agreed. Cleaning up after comments is also of course, necessary...

Comment: Yes - comments should be used to clarify the intentions of the OP, so I'd say, in a second language if necessary.

Comment: Similar situation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24465699/how-to-close-the-app

Comment: @AbhishekVerma I love that example, it perfectly illustrates how in some situations, with cleanup - it's a win/win situation.

Comment: Sometimes it would be much easier to read the question in the mothertongue of the OP and then translate it than to decipher "something-like-English". Perhaps the site could encourage the use of google translator or have a general option for other-language-posts that need to be translated first or something like that.

Comment: I noticed quite a few French/Francophones posting questions, one such as this one http://stackoverflow.com/q/43217450/1415724 where a comment posted was: *"English only questions please"* - Stack has a few other areas for coders in Spanish, Portuguese, Russian and maybe more that I don't know of, so that comment isn't fully correct. I have often wondered why there isn't a section for francophones setup. I've seen a lot of (new) members that come from various French-speaking countries that have a hard time explaining themselves in English, where Google translate doesn't always get it right.

Comment: Addendum to my above comment: Would this be worthy of a feature request?

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal Things often get lost in translation and Google doesn't always get it right; I know this firsthand when it comes to French and many expressions.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Go ahead and propose a French Overflow at http://area51.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @deceze Thanks for the link. I read it over this morning very carefully and by the looks of it, is more work than I thought (pardon my ignorance). At best, I think I may just suggest the following website (to francophones) which is about as best as it's going to get https://forum.phpfrance.com/

Answer (score 77):

Stack Overflow is English only. There even is [an official policy](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/) that has been set a long time ago and there are various discussion on MSE on the topic such as [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange). So yeah, it's an English only site. If you want to have a similar site in another language, then check on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) if there isn't already such a proposal, or create a proposal of your own. (A process which has lead to [Stack Overflow in Portuguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) for example)

Now let's get to the issue of providing a post in another language. You are kind enough to translate it to English and we have a clear post. Great, right? Well ... what if the post isn't entirely clear. It gets comments asking for clarification, yet the OP's English isn't good enough to respond clearly. Are you going to be around to help them all out? Then an answer comes in and this perfectly addresses the OP's translated question. But the OP perhaps doesn't know if that is a good answer. Does that have to be translated as well?

Bottom line is, the site is English. If your English is good enough to be understood, fine. If it's not, perhaps find another resource. But please don't post content in multiple languages or "help" the OP out by providing full translations. That will get complex and messy pretty fast.

Comment: There's often quite a gap between reading comprehension and ability to formulate your own ideas, so the OP would get the answers even if his english formulation of the question is mediocre. Think of the provided question in his native language only as clarifying hint to editors who *can read* it (not neccessarily write it).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - all very reasonable. I use SO regularly to find answers to my programming questions, but rarely do I spend the time afforded to me to scour pages upon pages of information about how the site is run. It must be annoying for long time users of the site to have to answer the same thing over and over, but keep in mind some of us are new to it... we don't mean to be pesky. :)

Comment: Regardless @Deduplicator, if (beyond the occasional minor edits) you need anyone to facilitate your interactions on the site at any point, you might be better off finding a different site. Either that or improve your language skills. And for a developer decent English skills are a good thing to have anyway.

Comment: No worries @wribit. I've spent a fair bit of time here so I know what to look for and (in the case of MSO content remaining on MSE) know where to look for it.

Comment: @wribit there's currently a proposal in Area 51 for [Stack Overflow in French](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/63820/programmation-stack-overflow-in-french).

Comment: As a native English speaker and Japanese learner, am I the only one that yearns for multi language support with SO? If posts were tagged with their respective language and then filtered if different from users preferential language(s), I don't see how this how this would be a problem.

Comment: Thanks @Cupcake, I'm checking that out now :)

Comment: @Michael That's worth a whole 'nother discussion... :) But, having worked exactly with this kind of thing, community driven, multilingual sites, I can tell you that this is an extremely tough proposition. People will "ghettoise" themselves anyway in that system based on their language barriers, so we might as well explicitly create that ghetto from the beginning on the right basis (Area 51 site creation process) instead of letting it grow out of control naturally and making it unmaintainable in the process.

Comment: @MichaelPetrie: besides, some language tags are already taken for questions working with that language, e.g. [arabic] is used to tag questions dealing with BiDi, positional forms, mirroring, and other issues that crop up when dealing with arabic UIs.

Comment: Those questions still primarily have to be written in English though @ninjalj. That the subject matter is Arabic text and all issues surrounding it doesn't change that.

Comment: @Bart: well, my point was that at this stage Michael's proposal would involve lots of confusion and retagging. Separate sites would be saner (at least than that proposal, I'm not arguing whether having separate sites by native language would be sane).

Comment: I don't see how avoiding the scenario outlined here is more valuable than the understanding that comes from communicating in your native language, as long as the post is edited with the results of the communication in English.

Comment: @deceze Agreed :) Extremely tough, but if that functionality was there I don't see how it would hurt. The Japanese equivalents to SO (http://chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/, for example) are abysmal in comparison. SO is such a great platform for sharing knowledge, it seems like such a shame that it should be limited to English only.

Comment: @MichaelPetrie As mentioned above there is a Portuguese SO and there might be a French one soon and maybe a Japanese/Chinese/Arabic one in due time. Only they are not under one umbrella which is good. Your suggestions with language tags is interesting but has a flaw. I imagine that everyone can select a range of languages and then only sees questions of these languages. But it would be a tough job for moderators or voters because they must be polyglot. And flagging for duplicates across languages.. From an efficiency point of view we better just all speak only one language whatever it will be.

Answer (score 13):

I always appreciate when users include both their attempt to pose the problem in English and, if they can't do so quite clearly, a version in another language as well. There are enough people on SO that someone who speaks the language in question will almost certainly be able to fix up the English version quickly. If such a person finds the question unclear in both languages and the OP is unable to explain it quickly, the question will surely be closed as unclear. If the OP does not understand the answers, that is unfortunate, but SO nonetheless benefits from good answers.

---

An extreme example of how a strict "English only" policy fails: I remember reading a question in which the OP stripped all the comments out of their code *because they were not in English*. Surely the question would have been better if the code had retained its (Spanish, I think) comments!

---

Some limits may be reasonable. Major world and regional languages like Chinese, Hindi, Arabic, Spanish, French, Russian, German, and Japanese are much more likely to find competent translators on SO than less-popular languages like Icelandic and Yoruba.

Comment: My gut feeling tells me that one shouldn't have to strip comments from code just because they aren't in english. But then this is kind of a slippery slope. If I had code commented in my mother tongue I would probably translate the comments - should be no problem if the question is already in english.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is Stack Overflow so exclusively English and does not accept an OP's question if they put in the time and effort to be well understood?

That is for one simple reason I believe. While there are developers in many other countries who speak their native language every day there always should be a way to delivery/distribute information. Without such exchange the worlds' development would be very hard. Therefore there is such a thing like `lingua franca`, which currently de facto is English language. I agree that people should make an effort to deliver their message/question despite language barrier. And as long as question/answer/comment can be understood, even if English is not 100% correct, this should be accepted and furthermore should be supported and edited by community. Alienating non-native speakers already creates things like:

- [SO in Turkish](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34945/stack-overflow-in-turkish)
- [SO in Spanish](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stack-overflow-in-spanish)
- [SO in Russian](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41168/stack-overflow-in-russian)
- [SO in Portugese (already launched)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/)

I fear that those will create more language barriers leading to isolation of information from other people who do not speak that language. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: In the end everyone is free to try to create his/her own community in any desired language but the interest will be low. Only about English as only lingua franca I'm not convinced. I guess Chinese could become a second one if they wanted it. Just imagine they would start a Chinese SO (or a Spanish or an Arabic) and there would be better answers than here. Some people might be driven to learn more Chinese (or Spanish or Arabic) because of this. So I'm not 100% convinced that there can be only one lingua franca. There may be more. But I completely agree about the barriers.

Comment: @Trilarion as off-topic - although I am not Chinese, I live and work in Shanghai, China. Their IT community is already very isolated due to low penetration of English language. But that doesn't mean they have great IT community. Because of that isolation, they still stuck in 90s (IT wise). For example their online banking while exists always require very old versions of IE (doesn't work in other browsers) which creates lots of problems for tech savvy people. My point is that such isolation isn't good for growth, and 2ndary point - Chinese can't be `lingua franca` because it is hard to learn...

Comment: @Trilarion It's unlikely that Chinese will become a lingua franca anytime soon. Those things evolve not by them being declared so, but because of cultural influence. English has arguably "won" because the whole world has been subjected to American culture for the better part of the last century, and because of the economical success America had. Before that it used to be French and to some extend German.

Comment: @Trilarion Contd. China on the other hand is not exactly "sharing" a ton of its culture as the USA is with the rest of the world, so few people are exposed to its language. Additionally, there's no basis for Hanzi (the writing system) in the West, so there's a huge barrier to entry. In order to learn a Hanzi based language, you pretty much have to be immersed in it 24/7 to retain all those characters. It's very very hard to learn with just a few hours per week in school. Not to mention the tone based pronunciation, which is an unknown concept in the West as well. Just too many hurdles here.

Comment: Pretty much the hyroglyphic type language sets present a big problem for non-speakers. The major advantage of the Latin character set is that even as a non-speaker of many European languages I can at least recognise some similarities between them, common root words etc... I haven't got a chance with the character sets of Japanese and Chinese languages for example. Also English will happily sleep around with other langauges and pick up whatever it likes from them. Its flexibility, lower barrier to entry, prevelance and adaptability make it ideal as a lingua franca - now a native English phrase.

Comment: @AlexKey Somehow I'm a bit surprised to hear about the backward state of chinese IT. I always thought since they produce all the IPhones and all the other hardware (with Taiwan and Korea ...) they should also have huge capabilities for programming and literally millions of programmers. But it seems they aren't yet there.

Comment: @Trilarion produce != design/develop. It is "produce" as in stand by assembly line and do all the cheap jobs.