# About a [tag:bilingual]

Tags: discussion, tags

I have come across SO questions where the asker struggles to frame the question in English, obviously because he is a not-native English speaker.
And most recently this question: [How to close the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24465699/how-to-close-the-app).
Another case in which SO user Deceze answered a good enough solution for this: [Non-native English speakers and asking a bilingual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261910/non-native-english-speakers-and-asking-a-bilingual-question).

I, personaly, think that a [bilingual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bilingual) tag would be a more unified approach to this. Also people, in no time, will be knowing, it's there and it's not illegal if I don't know much English.

For ex: A post tagged like [bilingual-hindi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bilingual-hindi) or maybe just [hindi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hindi) will have the entire question as if the quotation wasn't so that everyone can understand it and will also contain a quote in Hindi that briefs the question's base idea so that someone can edit the question to make it exactly what asker wants.

"I have created one android application....in my application the user press the home key on current activity or open activity , the application will be closed and if he open the activity again the launcher activity will be open ...i have done everything is right....

> I am not good at English and I am briefly explaining the question in this
>   quote, in Hindi. I know someone will come and edit the question for me. Also, I must be trying hard and framing the rest of question in English, as well."

This way a non-native English user would feel less alienated in SO. What do you think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tags should be about the content of the post, not about the question itself -- tags like these are commonly referred to as "meta-tags", which are removed on sight. [The Death of Meta Tags](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) explains why these sorts of tags are removed.

Where English is not a person's native language, there are three main "levels" of understanding:

1. Able to read/write in English to the point that it is completely understandable (but does not necessarily have perfect spelling/grammar/punctuation).
2. Has basic understanding of English, but not enough to be able to convey their meaning effectively.
3. Cannot read/write in English at all.

From what I understand, your proposal targets the second group. A user would (attempt to) post a question in English, so that it stands alone without the other language text. The user would then add to the question what they mean in their native language where they believe they are unable to convey what they mean.

To a certain extent in isolated cases, this is not particularly harmful. However, I have a few major concerns:

- Making this an "official" policy might make users expects others to improve the question for them, with relatively minimal effort. We have already grappled with the issue of users on the Internet expecting others to do their work for them, such as when you see questions asking like:

  > Hello, I need a forum urgently developed and I have 24 hours before deadline. My client now ask to add login functionality to code, but no idea what to do. Right now I have this code:
  >
  > ```
  > <?php echo 'Hello World!'; ?>
  > ```
  >
  > But that doesn't let me have logins. Can anyone help?

  Allowing others to create a dependence on others answering for them has been shown not to be effective, as we've seen in the past with "plz gimme teh codez" questions, and doesn't actually help them to learn to become independent. I'm afraid that doing this will not users to become proficient in asking questions in English, which in the end is our goal. As [Jeff Atwood succinctly puts it](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/):

  > **It is not our goal to teach English.** It is our goal to teach programming.
- This might create a community "divide" between those who understand the native language, and those who do not. If we have a question with very broken English, but perfectly fine explanation in (say) Hindi, then only people who know Hindi will be able to answer the question. People who understand the question may not necessarily edit the question to allow others to understand what it's actually asking for, practically creating two separate communities working against each other.

  That would have a corresponding increase in unanswered questions when we already have issues with questions remaining unanswered, with only 75% of questions answered. To compare, beta sites are expected to have at least 90% of questions answered, and quite a few of them have more than 95% of questions answered.

Most importantly: **we already have a solution that works**. In the vast majority of cases, comments are able to make a question understandable where the OP has some understanding of English. If someone does not know what the OP means, we can ask the OP a few questions in the comments to help clarify the question. Why should we try something when it's only in a minority of cases that this would actually apply?

Comment: Haven't I said that that the quote is just an additional information about the question and the the question itself. The question remains as it is

Comment: Oh I see! Thanks for explaining. BTW I didn't knew about meta tags.

Comment: Saw your edit. But that's not what I wanted to say. I simply meant that, the question remains as if it was asked without that particular bilingual quotation, so that everyone can understand it clearly. At the same time a quotation is appended to it so that someone can edit it and make it exactly how asker wants it to be. The quotation is just a brief and not the matter itself.

Comment: See the example in my question, I have updated it.

Comment: Aha! You are awesome at explaining things. Thanks again!