# How should questions in other languages than English be handled on SO?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, languages

I was reviewing new questions and found an answer in Spanish. To my understanding SO is a forum in English and thus I flagged the answer.

But this addresses the more general question of what languages, besides English are acceptable anywhere on SO.

I cannot find any guidelines in the ["good questions"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) FAQ.

There seems to have been a [discussion on acceptable languages in chats](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263092/disallow-languages-other-than-english-in-chat) but I cannot find any policy for the questions and answers.

Comment: It is duplicate. My search skills didn't show me the answer. Please vote to close.