# How to handle non-English chat flags

Tags: discussion, flags, chat

This morning I saw a bunch of flags from [The Great Gujarati Android Developers Ever !](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/93330/the-great-gujarati-android-developers-ever) chatroom:

[image: Chat flags]

The only message I could really make heads or tails of was

> U r intelligent Girl yar. I m impressed

which is neither offensive nor spam.  The others, I wasn't so sure of.  Even Google Translate couldn't provide me with a clear translation.

Do I let these flags sit as pending?  Are these really offensive?  Only voiced users can talk, so I couldn't even post a message asking users to stop flagging.

Comment: One possible solution : Nuke the chatroom.

Comment: @Sunshine I think that's a little extreme.  I'd like to give these users the benefit of the doubt.  I understand that we cannot actively moderate non-english chatrooms, but unless this is consistant behavior I don't think we should have to do that.  Maybe we can have a flag ban or flag warning, just like the "you have recently declined flags" warning on main?

Comment: ["If concerns are raised over the appropriateness of a room's conversation, then either the conversation or the entire room is subject to deletion"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/263092/2982225)

Comment: I can see how someone could get offended by that comment. A little more empathy...

Comment: Additionally, [from a linked SE post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136259/what-languages-are-we-allowed-to-speak-in-se-chat-rooms/136282#136282) in @Sunshine's link: `When there's any doubt as to the appropriateness of a conversation (for instance: it gets flagged) and it can't be understood, it should be deleted.`- Shog9♦

Comment: @Oded according to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-work) meta SE post: `Even if a post is a bad post for some reason or another, it is probably not offensive. The Offensive flag is meant to be used only in extreme cases, like hate speech, abuse against people, or abuse of the system.` Are you saying this is an extreme case?

Comment: @JAL - it isn't about me. It is about the person who flagged. Very possible that they *do* see it as an extreme case.

Comment: @Oded but it's not just about the user who flagged, it's also about the users reviewing the flag.  Since 10k+ users review the flag, what happens if they don't think it's offensive?  The flag is declined.  The user keeps flagging and the flag keeps getting declined.

Comment: That's why the guidance to 10k users is to validate these flags - we don't officially support non-English-language chat rooms and if they choose to misbehave and get flagged as a result, it is their own undoing.

Comment: @JAL The literal translation of these messages mean: 
1) Krupa What do you think about this conversation Krupa?
2) ha ha. Okay no problem. It happens, used to happen with me too before. (Source: I am a native Gujarati)
In any case I don't think its offensive or spam.

Comment: @JAL Also the 'yar' in `U r intelligent Girl yar. I m impressed` means buddy or mate.

Comment: @JAL I have to disagree that *U r intelligent Girl yar. I m impressed* is not offensive. When I first saw it it came across like the person was impressed that the girl was smart which to me makes me think they fell most women aren't smart. To me that is sexism and offensive.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Seriously? How deep do people have to read into things before they realize they might be being a bit silly?

Comment: @R_Kapp IMHO I didn't read to deep.  When I first saw that flag in chat my impression was as I explained above.  I really don't see a way that it is not sexist to be impressed that a girl is smart.  That may not be how you see it but it was my impression.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I don't know how old you are or where in the world you reside, but where I am from, it is quite common vernacular in the 20s-30s crowd to use, e.g., "Damn dude, ..." or "Damn girl, ... " before expressing some opinion of said person. This is not done to draw attention to the person's gender, but because "Damn person, ..." sounds *really* awkward. I fail to see how this is any different from that.

Comment: @R_Kapp if what the person meant was *damn girl you are smart, I'm impressed* then I would not have a problem with it.  If that was the case then I guess it was just lost in translation on me.

Comment: @NathanOliver: As someone whose parents are Indian, I'm fairly confident that's what was meant; I get "You're a smart boy" all the time from my older Indian relatives, while my wife gets "You're a smart girl". They can't be sexist both ways, can they?

Comment: @NathanOliver: *"U r intelligent Girl yar. I m impressed"* is not professional and it can be considered sexist if it is addressed to a stranger but it is not an *"extreme case, like hate speech, abuse against people, or abuse of the system"*

Comment: I wonder what language it is...

Comment: @R_Kapp "You're a smart boy" sounds condescending, giving possibly the impression of a superiority in age difference. In professional environments we just need to be sensitive. Don't give praise in a way that is embarrassing for the other party, but instead compliment in a way that shows respect. Born as a non-native English speaker, as I am, gives extra challenge. We all grow in maturity, and our mastering of the English language. Just don't fall for the 'culture' excuse.

Comment: Hard to tell with some of the "names" of people in this discussion whether up to now all the contributors have or have not been male, but as a "girl" I can say that I do NOT read any sexist connotations in the remark quoted by @NathanOliver.

Comment: @NathanOliver, I wonder if sexism is banned on SO; could you please enlighten me on the matter? And if it is actually banned then how to discern sexism from not sexism? Note, that "sexism" is not universally applicable notion. Some cultures just don't care.

Comment: @BoltClock, what does it mean "we don't officially support non-English-language chat rooms"? There are non-English sites on SE with associated   chat rooms where non-English languages are used.

Comment: @ixSci: Obviously by "we" I meant "stackoverflow.com" - the main English-language Stack Overflow site.

Comment: @BoltClock, I see. But flags work across the sites. So sometimes guys from different SE sites(non-Russian) come to react on a flagged chat message in a Russian stackoverflow chat. Based on this I think the rule is a bit strange since there are no borders for the flags and you can't always understand what site's chat you are currently in.

Comment: @ixSci: Flags on chat.SO stay on chat.SO. They aren't seen by the rest of the network chat. And this discussion is about the English-language SO and its own chat - which is why it's posted on Meta SO, not Meta SE.

Comment: @Nathan: _"I really don't see a way that it is not sexist to be impressed that a girl is smart"_ Oh brother. _That_ comment is sexist. Why must you take everything that even approaches relating to the female gender and demote it to "sexism"? Can't women be defined as something other than targets for sexism? Please? They can actually be smart y'know and we can comment on some women being smart. Just like we can comment on men being smart! For example: "you're a smart guy". This is not "offensive" for goodness's sake. Unless you want people not to reveal that women can be smart? I don't get it.

Comment: @R_Kapp `That can't be sexist both ways` You'd be surprised at the mental gymnastics some people manage to perform...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is why [we don't support non-English chatrooms on English sites](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263092/disallow-languages-other-than-english-in-chat).

I've frozen the room.

Comment: What happens when you freeze a room? I mean, does everybody just suddenly get locked out? Do you leave some sort of message as to why it was frozen? Frozen kind of implies a temporary state. Will it ever be unfrozen, or is it over and done? I'm just curious. I don't really know anything about chat.

Comment: I did leave a message, @mike. The room is readable but not writable by non-mods; it also doesn't show up in active lists by default. Essentially just keeps it around for discussion since this thread exists.

Comment: @Mike M.: Also, freezing is meant to be a permanent state; once frozen a room cannot be unfrozen by anybody except a mod. Timeouts are used for temporarily silencing a room.

Comment: Yes @Mike. Shog's message - [Can't read -> can't moderate.
English-only, folks.](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/93330)

Comment: Oh, nifty. How'd you get to the transcript, @Sunshine?

Comment: Go to chat -> All Rooms and view the info of any room @Mike, [and select "View Transcript"](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/93330/the-great-gujarati-android-developers-ever)

Comment: Oh, duh. The button's even bright orange. I guess I was looking for something much more obvious. Thanks, @Sunshine!

Answer (score 18):

Some givens:

- The message is not in English
- The message cannot be discussed because the room is locked
- The message was flagged

The first two make it very hard to enter the room and discuss what happened. It does not seem like there was malice to me, but it is very hard to tell even now after having some back and forth in comments.

As a result of not being able to get feedback, or determine if the message was in fact disrespectful, it is nearly impossible to invalidate these flags with certainty.

> **To be on the safe side these flags should be validated. If the room itself wishes to not be susceptible to this type of instant validation of flags, then it should remove its locked status and it will be a lot easier on everyone.**

As it stands, the room itself is not abiding by the rules of Stack Overflow - English is the main language used here and the "third place" (chat) is expected to follow the same standards as its host exchange which is Stack Overflow. That said, this room has over one hundred thousand messages and dismissing it out of hand from one seemingly innocent exchange would be cruel and excessive.

Should the validation of flags on non English messages become excessive rooms should seriously consider switching to English.

However, none of this should be interpreted as a thumbs up to go on a message flagging spree. If you can understand the message, and it is offensive, then that is fair but simply flagging chat messages because they are in another language is going to be jarring on everyone and serve no real purpose.

Comment: So are you suggesting the chat room be nuked if this behavior continues?

Comment: @Zizouz212: That does not scale, nor do we have any particular reason to induct you as an authority without further validation that your provided translations are accurate.

Comment: @Zizouz212 That's not right. `Hun gujarati ma vaat karu chu` means I speak Gujarati. Your gujarati does not make sense at all.

Comment: @JAL - Nope. Just saying that more flags may end up being validated if this continues. Nuking isn't my call to make, and personally I wouldn't support doing that to a room with so much activity that seems to be as on topic as other rooms for the most part.

Answer (score -5):

I believe freezing the room may be a harsh decision but at the same time I also agree that moderators can not understand the language to verify the raised flags.

My thoughts:

- Why should language be an obstacle to carry out technical discussions? (Given chat room has owners and moderates it regularly and sets rules for the chat room.)
- Chat rooms should not be access restricted for moderators so that on flag abuse they can go and give a warning.
- User abusing flags should be suspended/ penalized for raising inappropriate flags.