# Merge chat.SO into chat.SE

Tags: feature-request, chat

This has been in the back-burner long enough. There isn't any good reason other than historical that prevent this.

I'm aware that this will **remove some complexities on chat.SE**, since the SO moderators have to keep moderator status in chat.SE. We would have a **larger pool of moderators** so we would get more diversity of timezones and wealth of experience, also this seems to be important for the SO community since in last elections users were worried that there was little presence of moderators in chat. The proportion users/moderators on chat.SE is higher than in chat.SO, so in average even the size of SO shouldn't add much more than a single extra flag to handle weekly (I counted just now, utc time 15:17, more moderators than users in chat.SE). Will obviously reduce the amount of drama (or heighten it), since events will be more distributed. And lastly, SO moderators will have more time to moderate the main site instead of dealing with chat.

I listed what I consider pro's of merging chat.SO and chat.SE, because I couldn't think of any detrimental effect that we already ain't experiencing.

Let me put this for those that doesn't know: **for the end user, this change will be imperceptible.** chat.SO will redirect to chat.SE, will present all the same rooms that are associated with Stack Overflow, the same rooms and with their complete transcripts. The stared messages may be lost, but that's easily solvable.

Comment: I wonder if it might be worthwhile to consider merging ALL chats, network-wide. Do any other sites have problems like we do?

Comment: @Laurel there are only 3 chat servers: MSE, SO and SE. There were plans of merging MSE with SE's but it has more edge cases (they have company only private rooms in MSE chat). From this, the most straightforward merge is just SO and SE chats, since there wouldn't be any edge case.

Comment: Goes to show you I don't use chat. I'll take your word for it.

Comment: I don't get it.  Chatting about SO topics (technical) vs chatting about meta/all-sites (not technical) has no edge cases and is comparable?   You'll have to flesh that out.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not taking the topics into account. Just the technical aspects of the chat servers and some perks that will come along with this move. As I said at the start this has been in the back burner long enough.

Comment: This would also fix http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323810/how-can-we-support-languages-other-than-english-in-stack-overflows-chat. SO would no longer need different chat policies to all other sites.

Comment: Where does http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com fit?

Comment: @Flexo "There were plans of merging MSE with SE's but it has more edge cases" so, unless those edge cases are solved, "the most straightforward merge is just SO and SE chats, since there wouldn't be any edge case"

Comment: I don't see how merging the two solves any of the actual issues chat has (from a user POV).

Comment: @PeeHaa I'm not trying to solve any issue.

Comment: So why are you requesting something if you are not trying to solve something? What's the gain? Seems rather useless.

Comment: @PeeHaa **"will remove some complexities on chat.SE"**, **"have a larger pool of moderators"**, **"SO moderators will have more time to moderate the main site instead of dealing with chat"**? Everything was listed on the question.

Comment: What complexities of chat.se? Why do we need a larger pool of moderators? [As stated, your proposal does nothing to solve the actual issues of chat.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324023/merge-chat-so-into-chat-se?noredirect=1#comment350342_324023)

Comment: @PeeHaa chat.SE hosts the Teacher Lounge which is the defacto chat room for all moderators and important announcements are done in that room. Non-moderators don't have access to that room, therefore, SO moderators, due being unable to link their chat account with the site they are moderators, can't access the room. The solution implemented was to manually assign moderator status to those users. I'm not sure why are you against having a larger pool of moderators considering the featured post in the Community Bulletin and recent [tag:chat] discussions.

Comment: @PeeHaa you are saying "actual issues chat has (from **a user POV**)" I don't take into account *any user* but the underlying chat system. The change will be imperceptible for most users.

Comment: Not sure if you are willingly not reading or just trolling at this point. I am going to try it one last time "I don't see how merging the two solves any of the actual issues chat has (from a user POV)."

Comment: @PeeHaa you are not listening to me: **the user doesn't matter**. I'm not thinking about them at all. This is a FR to the SE team.

Comment: Well if that is the only thing you can come up with to warrant a change like this I am sorry, but this is a terrible idea for <strike>no</strike> very little gain imo.

Comment: I think doing this could be a solution to: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323810/how-can-we-support-languages-other-than-english-in-stack-overflows-chat-and?cb=1

Comment: The solution to that problem is not allow non English in chat. The solution to needing moderators is fixing the flagging system and giving more powers/knobs to turn to room owners. The solution to broken search and markdown in chat is all on balpha. None of this is fixed by moving rooms.

Comment: @PeeHaa who said I'm trying to solve problems that users face?

Comment: @HansPassant:  [A quick glance at the list](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) suggests that there are chatrooms there that do have some basis in technical detail, and some that don't.  The key difference that I can see is that Stack Overflow's chat has [half as many rooms](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/), but even then it's superficial.  You can filter rooms and search for them based on their name, so I'm not sure if your concern is entirely valid since it seems to be well mitigated.

Comment: I seem to recall the reason for having them be separate domains was server/network related. E.g. too much traffic. Has that been addressed by the company yet?

Comment: @TylerH I've never seen such claims. But, and just to have something, right now there are 97 users on chat.SO and 186 users on chat.SE. Sadly, there are no more stats about this (maybe fiddling around with archive.org?)

Comment: @TylerH oh, and the chat servers are hosted on virtual servers. I can't find the source right now, and Nick's blog doesn't tells https://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/11/22/what-it-takes-to-run-stack-overflow/. Ok I was looking at the wrong post https://nickcraver.com/blog/2016/02/17/stack-overflow-the-architecture-2016-edition/ "The second cluster is a set of Dell R730xd servers, each with 768GB of RAM, 6TB of PCIe SSD space, and 2x 8 cores. This cluster runs everything else. That list includes Careers, Open ID, **Chat**, our Exception log, and every other Q&A site."

Comment: At first I thought the split was intentional, on grounds that where you earned your rep matters, similarly to how the new tag rep threshold on SO is so much higher than elsewhere. But then I realized that UNIX, SU, and Server Fault are on chat.SE despite being as technical as SO.

Answer (score 16):

This seems like pointless work.

The moderators on chat.SE may be chatting with *each other* rather than moderating, which explains their higher count, not moderating.

Saying to the moderators "I notice you like chatting.  How about we interrupt your chat time with more flags to handle by merging a chat board with flags into your chat board?" is moving work around, not reducing work.

If there was evidence of a moderation problem on either board, there could be some dividends, but even then a stronger argument than the OP would be required to be convincing.

"It is on the back burner" is *not* an argument to do it, but rather an argument against (it has failed to be important enough to prioritize repeatedly, why should today be any different?)

Negative downsides, beyond the work, include the inevidible glitches that will result (I could list a myriad of possibilities: bookmarks, shortcuts, redirects, name collisions, and that doesn't even get into backend issues), culture clash (Is moderator response different on the two boards?  If merged, which culture is used?  How can you be convinced that this could possibly be a universal good?), etc.

In short, if it ain't broke, don't fix it.  And nothing in your feature request mentions anything broke.

Comment: one big advantage I see is that I can have all my favorite rooms in one place...

Comment: "culture clash (Is moderator response different on the two boards? If merged, which culture is used? How can you be convinced that this could possibly be a universal good?)" Culture of a room isn't not above common rules of chat. If you want to have your own culture in a chat room, and that goes against what is expected on SE, **just don't use SE chat at all.**

Comment: @Braiam chat.SE and chat.SO may or may not have similar culture.  I don't know.  But, if you merge them, there will almost certainly be culture clash.  This is an actual cost.  Saying "there is no culture but the rules" is, quite frankly, a position that seems increadibly unreasonable, and doesn't match my experience on any social forum, online or off.  When you take two different cultures and shove them together, there is almost always damage: if there is a *reason* to do it, that can easily outweigh the damage, but saying "there is no damage" is not a reasonable response to the problem.

Comment: "here will almost certainly be culture clash" how? Most people will never know there's a bunch of new rooms in the server unless 1) they search for it, or 2) there are flags. On the first, they were going away from Kansas, so Dorothy can't expect everything to be the same, and on the second, people will just bring [popcorn](http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=popcorn&user=&room=) and watch the show unfolds. So, from my point of view you don't know c.SE at all or have serious misconceptions how stuff works.

Comment: I find the assumption there will be a culture clash **highly** annoying. Because that assumes there would be a need to actually interact unless there's flags. And that simply isn't the case. It's just a few hundred more chatrooms on the same sever. no big deal. Flag-Handling should be by the same standard across both servers **either way**

Answer (score 15):

I agree with you.

**When all SE networks chats are at one place why SO chat rooms are kept separately?**

I don't see any reason of why they are kept separately. I would love to see all SE and SO chatrooms at one place.

**We are not just technical people**

I am not just technical person. I am active on other SE networks as well. So, I don't think we should divide chatrooms based on technical and non-technical. IMO, we should not divide the chatrooms on any other aspects.

As said by [Ven](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324023/merge-chat-so-into-chat-se?cb=1#comment349756_324067),

> one big advantage I see is that I can have all my favorite rooms in one place...

I hope SO don't have any problem with merging these chat rooms.

Answer (score -5):

- There is little to no value to combining them.
- There is a noticeable cost to user experience, development time, and an increased chance of problems.

Unless they are doing a large amount on the chat system already, it will not be worth the expense.

Comment: "There is a noticeable cost to user experience, development time, and an increased chance of problems." [citation needed]

Comment: "There is a noticeable cost to user experience, development time, and an increased chance of problems." 
- Common sense

Comment: @Braiam The costs are obvious, which is why I did not provide citation.  The user experience suffers because users will have to adjust to the new site and the new rules.  It takes to do software changes, that is just the way it is.  When you change something (especially if it has so much data attached to it) there is a chance that the new changes will break something.  This is all basic software development/engineering, so SO users should understand this.

Comment: @Trisped no... for the user, for third time already, **there will be absolutely no difference**. None. If you visit http://chat.askubuntu.com, you are redirected to chat.stackexchange.com with the host askubuntu.com. It will be exactly the same thing in this case. And your other claim is reversed because we would have to support 1(2 actually) chat servers instead of 2(3). And chat.SE has to, for example, take into account special cases. Now, tell me, have you actually used chat.SE, chat.MSE and chat.SO? How long?

Comment: To pick a point:  what new rules, specifically, would a normal denizen of chat have to get used to if it were moved over to Meta Stack Exchange?

Comment: @Makoto none. none whatsoever

Comment: @Vogel612:  That's what I thought, but I'd like to see if Tripsed has any other considerations that either of us are missing.

Comment: @Braiam URL redirects do not account for all user interaction with the site.  The SO chat users will be expecting a particular experience, including a theme to the channels, which will no longer be there.  In addition, how the rules are applied differs greatly between sites.  You claim they are no new rules, but having visited other SE sites, I can tell you that the SE rules (which are written the same for all sites) are applied differently for each site.  You can claim that they are the same, but my experience proves you wrong.

Comment: @Trisped in what way is the different application (on site) relevant to chat? Chat moderation is pretty uniform across all three servers. Why would themes be an issue? Chatrooms do already have different themes (based on the sites they are associate with), so that argument's out.

Comment: But each chat has its own set of rules, its own topic, and its own norms, and the room owners choose how to enforce those (while concurrently, they channel *should* in principle also enforce the global rules).  Theme aside, I'm personally not seeing any evidence to back your claims up.

Comment: @Braiam Supporting 2 active servers requires a minimal amount of work unless there are multiple changes presented or there is a problem with the resources being used.  Servers are meant to be maintained with minimal effort from IT.  Compare this to the amount of time to add the redirects, re-code the SE to point to the correct site, and make the transition as seamless as you claim it will be, and you have a poor time investment.

Comment: @Vogel612 Theme and moderation issues are two different points.  As you point out, they do not combine well.

Comment: @Braiam  If you need more evidence, the fact that they have not done it is a good indication that it is not worth the effort to them, yet.  Considering the state of Chat, they are probably planning some major changes.  Combining all of these changes together makes a lot of sense (as pointed out in my answer).

Comment: The fact that they have not done it likely stems back to the time when Stack Overflow simply *was* its own site and the rest of the Stack Exchange network built around it.  Still not a convincing argument on your part.

Comment: @Makoto So they did not make the change because they did not do it that way to begin with?  That makes no sense.  Sure, it might be the way that it is because of their previous strategies, but that does not mean they will not need to work to fix it.  If anything, it implies that they will have more work to do to bridge the gap between systems and implementations.

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding my intent here.  I'm looking for you to provide some concrete evidence that validates your opposition to the migration to chat.  Merely going off of supposition which could be refuted otherwise isn't going to get either of us anywhere.

Comment: @Makoto I have provided as concrete as I can (common development knowledge).  It is now your turn to provide evidence that your assumptions are correct.  The fact is, if the change was easy, they would have done it already.  Either it is not easy or they have other priorities they want to work on (just listen to the pod casts).  Add in the fact that the overall value is low, and Braiam's assertion "_This has been in the back-burner long enough._" is completely incorrect.  Braiam even implies that the change has no value when he states "_I'm not trying to solve any issue._"

Comment: @Makoto themes are imported from the site automagically. I expect to see the same old SO theme as other sites.

Comment: Since it does not seem clear, the theme I mentioned in a previous comment was regarding the content of the chat channels, not the color/layout of the pages.

Comment: @Trisped soo... you're talking about topics. That makes even less sense than the consideration of themes. In addition to that your "Common development knowledge" is asserting there are circumstances that (Based on information publicily available) I (and Braiam and Makoto) think there are not. Your claims are unfounded and unfactual. Just because a change is easy it doesn't have to be done. In general your answer and the accompanying comments reek of unprepared talk :/

Comment: @Vogel612 The same could be said about yours.  How much information do you have on SE and SO source code?  Past pod casts have made it clear that they set the priority based on value vs work as and that the "side" projects are distinct code bases which cannot be easily merged into similar projects.  You asset that the three of you believe it will be easy to do the transition, but go to any software consulting company and they will disagree. The comments on this answer and the page in general reek of arm chair chastisement.  Where is your proof? Where is your evidence? Does SE history support?

Comment: I would gladly go through the transcripts of Tavern on Meta and hunt down all the comments done by [balpha](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/chat/topusers) about all my claims, since they exist. But leaving you in the wrong seems to be more entertaining. Next time, get your stuff together before deciding to form an opinion over anything. This is an advise.

Comment: @Braiam Feel free to go through the transcripts. It won't change the meaning or value of my answer to your request, it is not worth it. The fact is that your question has 25 down votes, does not address multiple concerns (which you admit in comments) and only 3 commentators (including you) trying to defend it shows how little value the community sees in it. Having done similar work before, I can tell you it is way more complicated than it seems unless the chats really are the same in every point. They will probably do a much more complete solution instead of following your sloppy suggestion.

Comment: @Trisped Well it also has 50 upvotes, I don't see how is that relevant. In fact it would imply community support.

Comment: @Tunaki the up to down ratio is enough to denote community interest.  The fact that over 1/3 of the votes are down indicates that it is controversial.  Take the statics on the up/down votes on meta, the views to votes ratio, and the fact that it was a featured meta post and the implication is still that the community doesn't really care enough for the change to be worth the cost.