# Why there is partiality and we can't get perfect solutions?

Tags: discussion, support, languages

I thought [How can we support languages other than English in Stack Overflow's chat… And should we?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323810/how-can-we-support-languages-other-than-english-in-stack-overflows-chat-and/323823#323823), was about to take views of Stack Overflow chat users whether we can use other languages (except English) or not.

We had given our opinion there, for the first two or three days all the SO users were supporting us with votes and comments. After that we only got downvotes. Why?

The current situation is:

- [Arpit Patel's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323851/1318946) got +8  -27 => -19
- [Piyush Gupta's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323850/1318946) got +10  -20 => -10
- [Arth Tilva's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323836/1318946) got +17  -24 => -7
- [My answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323823/1318946) got +22  -27 => -5

and after all the discussion we didn't get any solution, we just had a discussion and took each others' opinions.

Questions still open:

- We are helping by chatting on SO Groups? Is it really partiality to whom, who wants to do help really? *[ed: no idea]*
- Do we have a clear answer on whether to use languages other than English in chat rooms or not?

Comment: what is `perfect solutions` ?

Comment: The voting pattern could be due to 1) geographic differences and 2) a 'mob' effect - people are more likely to downvote a post which already has a negative score. Remember that votes on Meta often indicate agreement/disagreement, instead of post quality.

Comment: @Glorfindel We already have 25 to 30 upvotes and directly it down in minus.

Comment: @Shubhank Any solution, whatever we had discussed there, nothing to summation.

Comment: then please keep the question with a general tone rather then over exaggerating things. You will get better answers with it.

Comment: I have no idea why you're expecting a "perfect solution"; those frequently don't exist, especially for something complicated like *supporting all languages ever*. Also, a little perspective would be handy: there are 6 other answers with negative scores written by non-Indians (presumably Americans, mostly, although who knows?), half of which are scored lower than your own post. So it's not partiality: there's just a lot of bad ideas (or ideas that a lot of meta users think are bad) on that question.

Comment: Also the problem there is that there are multiple answers for the same ideas (good work, everyone) so it's hard to be clear on where the community stands. That said, the obvious winner at the moment is banning non-English on chat.SO but allowing it on chat.SE. I'm not sure what point you're trying to make about the voting (non-English issues again, I guess). My answer is negatively scored and you don't even mention it, what gives?

Comment: Many answers in that question were not really very helpful to the discussion. When the question is "how can we make this very complicated thing work? *Can* we? Are there any volunteers that would be willing to try?", then answers that say "I think we should have this!" just don't add much

Comment: To add to that: _"I think we should allow other languages because SO is about sharing / because I don't speak English very well"_ is answered there multiple times. Those don't answer the question.

Comment: *After that we only got downvotes*.  I'd guess that the chat room members voted early.  These kind of voting rings are pretty evil.  The question was not about opinions and not a popularity contest, it asked for *solutions* to the moderation problem with these chat rooms.  "We like the room" is a useless opinion, not a solution.

Comment: Have a look at [this graph](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PObto.png). Only one of the mentioned answers in question started with a positive score on the first day. So these answers **were controversial from the beginning**. There were upvotes after the first day as well, but the downvotes prevail.

Comment: I agree with the downvoting, but I'm not sure why this needed to be *closed.* It doesn't seem particularly unclear - it just demonstrates a misunderstanding what Shog's question was about.

Comment: To all big heads , don't play politics here .where we newbies go to find solutions ? It clearly seems serial down votes to the post who want to remove that #language barrier .and don't hope much from this post @PratikButani ,this might be down voted as past , I guess rest of the respected developers wants to  continue their rigid thinking rather than providing any solution !!

Comment: @Radhe: There are no politics at play here. This question just isn't very good...

Comment: @Cerbrus I dont know english that is the biggest problem of my life. :) :)

Comment: You're never too old to learn.

Comment: Thanks to everyone, I think, I have try to learn English now more than Android.

Comment: @Radhe also there are no hashtags on SO. Allowing non-English chat isn't removing the language barrier, it's *adding one*.

Comment: Even for people with poor language comprehension skills (like me, I didn't speak a word of english until a couple of years ago) its possible to learn decent conversation level english in a year or less. What helped me particularly is jumping into english only communities and making it work. (By googling meanings of words, often if necessary, having a dictionary next to you, speaking with people, etc). Its definitely possible to learn english quickly, even in your free time. You should give it a shot @PratikButani, it will be an amazing asset for your career.

Comment: @Radhe what's YOUR solution for that then? Fix the language barrier. Shog wrote a question basically asking for multilingual users to moderate these rooms. It means there is a will from Stack to do this. When you ask a question for moderation and get answer like "plz give us the room, it's helpful".. It makes me believe no one understood why Shog posted his question. And your comment here tends to show how little you understand the issue and how we need this moderated.

Comment: @Patrice ,You are more experienced person then me , and about my comments , we also want solution ,but not getting any output after discussion .what xyz person got !! **downvoted** for their post and suggestion.

Comment: @Radhe you want solutions? THEN SUGGEST ONE. It's as simple as that. We are a community and come up with these TOGETHER. The other post looks like stack offering to go the extra mile for non English speakers.... And no one picking up the ball. We are community moderated. For us to support other languages, we'll need translators. As much as id like to help.... I only know French, English, and Spanish. If there was a blaring need for a French-English RO... Id potentially step up. But if i don't step uo, i wouldnt complain either. We are ALL part of the solution, but the solution has to be more

Comment: @radhe than just "accept us but we won't try to meet you halfway". Also, downvotes on meta mean disagreement... So getting downvoted when people don't agree this will be helpful (which, since when i read them no one fo the answers in this post included anything about someone stepping up to the moderation job), downvotes are to be expected.

Comment: @Patrice ,not argu with you sir. if you think so !! sorry from my side , about my solution , other developers already posted his suggestion to fix this .you can check the previous post ,that was closed.apart form this let the developer above 1K reputation ,headlining flag first in particular chat room ,rather than disturbing moderators to fix that unnecessary flags.

Comment: @Magisch Even so, it is still easier to learn English if one's native language is a Germanic or Latin language. If one's native language is an Asian language, then the difference is a lot bigger, and it is harder to learn. Just to be clear on this, I'm _not_ saying it's easy for Westerners to learn English. Only that it's harder for some than for others.

Comment: @S.L.Barth While that may be correct, im also notoriously bad at learning languages (like, seriously, maybe 10 percentile), so if I can do it, im confident most people can.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, you've misunderstood the point of the question. Shog suggested a new system where normal dual-language users (for example, users well versed in both Gujarati and English) would commit to moderating the room, and help communicate problems to the moderators.

The answers were expected to discuss whether or not that proposal can hold, and whether people are interested in doing so.

At the moment of writing this answer, **we still do not allow languages other than English in our chat rooms**, because we don't have an effective way to moderate them.

Comment: Thank you :) I dont have any words. **Tough time never last but Tough people do.**