# Chatting in other language

Tags: discussion, chat, languages

I saw this: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129817/discussion-between-sanzeeb-aryal-and-ujwal-dhakal). And continued the chat in the native language, noticing that he knows the language. I didn't know the discussion would still be public. What should I do now?

Comment: Did you have your question answered in the chat? If so, it might be worthwhile to edit in the extra relevant details into their answer (assuming it's not substantially different from their original answer - otherwise you can post your own), and then mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Why would you think it would be appropriate to *chat* in a language other than English when you already know it would be inappropriate to *comment* in a language other than English?

Comment: @CodyGray I thought it wouldn't be public in the chat and it was much easier to communicate with that particular user in my native language, so i did and admitted the mistake. what should i do now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's not much you can do; chat messages become fixed after a few minutes.

We've had a [long discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323810/812149) about chatting in different languages. Basically, we want chat to be in English, so that the moderators can judge what happened if something gets flagged.

Did anything in your chat get flagged? Was there anything that would upset people? If there was, you could flag one of your own posts or messages, and ask a moderator to remove the chat.

If there were no problems in the chat (no insults, no quarrels, no things that a reasonable person would find offensive).... just leave it.

Almost everything you do on Stack Overflow is public; the only things that are private are votes and flags.

So, you should have used English in chat, as anywhere on the English Stack Overflow.
But unless there were problems in that chat, it's not a big deal. Just use English next time.

Comment: Flags aren't really private, either… They're just less public. Moderators still see them with your name attached.

Comment: @CodyGray I wouldn't call that "public". Maybe we should call their visibility "protected" rather than "private" :-)