# What does it mean to have negative score?

Tags: support, profile-page, meta, tag-badges, tag-score

My super inability is to walk passing things without seeing them. But today, I suddenly realised that I have a score of -11/100 on my stackoverflow meta profile!

'Is it normal?' I asked myself. Quickly, I went into investigation mode.

Numerous profiles of other users were browsed, none of them had negative scores.

[image: Neg]

What does it mean to have a negative score?! I have heard about 1 star places and services, but I have never encountered -1 star places/services/person, let alone -11 scored persons/users.

Comment: A chat score of -11 is reasonable good I would say, given your chat habits ;)

Comment: Wot? I am the sweetest and most obedient Telkitty I have known of, always in the top 100% of ALL users. @rene

Answer (score 9):

If you look to the left of the area you showed in the screenshot, you'll see that you have the [chat](/questions/tagged/chat) tag chosen as the tag badge to track. That's what the "score" and "answer" progress bars are referring to.

[image]

And you currently have [one answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323810/how-can-we-support-languages-other-than-english-in-stack-overflows-chat-and/323922#323922) in the [chat](/questions/tagged/chat) tag, which has a score of −11.

Comment: Why has the 'chat' tag been chosen as the tag badge to track?

Comment: @TelKitty Did you complete any badges recently?

Comment: Hard to say, I'm not familiar with the selection algorithm. It makes sense that it would select a tag badge to track where you were...further along. Do note that you can change it using the gear/cog icon to the side. Perhaps you picked [[meta-tag:chat]] at some point for the lulz? @TelKitty

Comment: @Gimby Not to my knowledge.

Comment: @CodyGray No, I wouldn't know how to do that.

Comment: You wouldn't know how to press buttons? That doesn't sound like any kitty I know...

Comment: Wot? How many kitties do you know??!