# Why am I banned from chat?

Tags: discussion, support, chat, moderation

I got the below message in Stack Overflow chat.

[image]

But I didn't post anything wrong. The inappropriate content link redirected me here. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/messages/34757984/history

I didn't void any rules that mentioned in the following links. Then why?

> 1. https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior
> 2. https://stackexchange.com/legal/content-policy

Comment: One of the RO's kicked you.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ i'm sure they were not. It might be the mod. I just want to know the reason.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ This is a full chat suspension, not a room kick.

Comment: FYI (as mentioned in the link in my comment): only you, the room's owners and moderators can see that message. The rest of us cannot see it and thus cannot give guidance on any rule violations. You'll have to copy the message content in your question here if you want us to see it.

Comment: @Stijn Yes i can do but that message is in Tamil (My mother tongue). You might not understand that. that's why i didn't posted.

Comment: From what I can see, it may be related to the fact you're chatting in a language other than English. The room you're most active in [was warned](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/34361411#34361411) to stick to English... I suggest you do.

Comment: @Cerbrus Good find. The next message by that moderator also gives a hint as to what happened.

Comment: @Cerbrus But that was not mentioned anywhere in http://stackexchange.com/legal/content-policy... How can they suspend me without knowing what it was. Please tell me why don't we converse in our language. We don't use tamil speak with peoples who don't know tamil

Comment: @SankarRaj: [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323439/non-english-discussions-in-se-chat/323479#323479) is why chat is English-only. Stack Overflow ___is___ an english site. It's ___impossible___ to moderate when other languages are allowed.

Comment: Well boy, people sure make the announcement frequently enough in that room. There is no argument from ignorance to be made.

Comment: @CodyGray: [Damn](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=english&room=81492), you're right. The room should be well-aware of SO's policy regarding the used language.

Comment: @PierreLebon so can i chat in my language, if that room is private?

Comment: @SankarRaj, -"How can they?" Just by clicking your name! -"But there are rules I didn't void any of them." This is not the law that is barely guidance for new user. The only law is the moderator! -"But this is against my right to kick me for 30 minutes for using my noble mother tongue!"You have been advised young Padawan. No one wants to be distracted by 2 French speaking about cheese in the chat. This could have been the more important sentence of your life. The fact that it uses 'mother tongue encryption' make it a disturbance in the force. That is not a private room.

Comment: @SankarRaj: There is no such thing as "Private" rooms on SO.

Comment: @Cerbrus Yes i know the non-english contents cannot be moderated. But I don't understand why you people are expecting english in chat also. No one will hurt if two people speaking in their language. They might have no idea about that.

Comment: The content can not be moderated, so it can not be allowed on the site. People could be harassing each other in a different language. How is SO supposed to act on that if they can't read the harassment?

Comment: There is no private. And as you can see even my grammatically incorrect English is annoying to them. It's easy to speak, our native language. But when speaking into tchat and even in the forum we are speaking to every Jedi that lived or will. We must speak to them in the more intelligible way

Comment: @PierreLebon: There is no "Private" on Stack Overflow. The site is English-only. It's really that simple.

Comment: Why do you keep calling it "tchat", @pierre? What is the leading T for?

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about something else, I edited my comment the seconde I posted it.

Comment: Because i'm french! for us Chat is Cat so they add an extra T. and because i have been using in for so long i nearly convinced myself that it was the correct in English.

Comment: @SankarRaj, don't be mad! I know it's annoying. They do it for a greater good. As they can't understand you they can't tolerate it. It's not against any language. It's not against any culture. It's just because its "encrypted" . Try to speaing using any cypher on chat you will get kick.

Comment: @PierreLebon Okay. I have removed that. I do accept what you've said. But i can't said i will stick to english rather than I may not chat here anymore. Its not because of English. But i refuse to speak other languages with my native people..

Comment: Chat is great, no hard feeling! Take your time. Come back when you need to.

Comment: @PierreLebon May be :). Thanks for your support and information.

Comment: @Cerbrus *"There is no such thing as "Private" rooms on SO"* there so such thing as "Private" on the internet

Answer (score 11):

You have been suspended automatically, via a a spam or offensive flag. You probably have a pretty good idea of what exactly you've said that deserved such a flag.

From [A guide to moderating chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271267/a-guide-to-moderating-chat):

> When a spam/offensive flag is validated on a message in chat, the message is deleted and the author of the message is suspended for 30 minutes. If the author is already suspended, that suspension is extended by 30 minutes. Note that moderator flags take effect immediately (see above for details).

Comment: Yes, if you have an idea of which message it could be, you should find a *(removed)* line and you can check the message history. [Otherwise, you'll have to jump through some hoops](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134917/can-a-user-non-moderator-see-deleted-chat-messages-on-stackoverflow).