# It would be usefull ask a quest.i.o.n in spanish? / Sería útil hacer una pregunta en español?

Tags: discussion

I would like to know if there's is value in adding the question in other language like Spanish?.

Me gustaría saber si agrega valor el incluir la pregunta en otro lenguaje como el Español?

Comment: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stack-overflow-in-spanish

Comment: thanks a lot for the link, it's not visible in any question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there's not much value to it at all.  Since Stack Overflow is an English-only site, questions (or answers) asked in another language tend to get closed.

If you were to post your question in both English and Spanish, at *best* the Spanish would be edited out, and at *worst* the question would be put on hold.

[There is a standing proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stack-overflow-in-spanish) for Stack Overflow in Spanish; it looks like it's not that far off from launching, and I'd encourage you to commit to it so you can participate in its beta launch.

Answer (score 1):

There is, for each site on SE, a meta page for such questions: questions about the site, not the sites topic. This particular question has been around for ages - since the beginning of SO, and there are many threads and good answers on Meta.

To go to Meta, click on the little down arrow next to StackExchange in the top bar.

As dezeze pointed out, there is also area51, a place to propose new sites. If they get enough traction, there at a time will be a specific site for a specific topic.

I agree though that SO is to be kept in English. Imagine having to plow through questions in multiple foreign languages. I am sure you will find somebody to help with the English if necessary. There might be a way for this, as proposed in this [meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261910/non-native-english-speakers-and-asking-a-bilingual-question/262006#262006) and its accepted answer.

Comment: the question is not for having trouble with the language, it's for adding more value to the SO search machine

Comment: @ChristianCuadrosBetancur, if only a few questions were bilingual, you would potentially miss the correct answer to your question and maybe end up creating a duplicate if searching in that foreign language. And we cannot ass translations to all questions in all languages spoken in SO. I guess that would not help but add to confusion. But ask the question on META, where it belongs, maybe others see that differently.